# Reversing django.contrib.auth.models.User password, sha1 to readable string

Tags: django, encryption

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = User.objects.get(username='test')
user.password
u'sha1$c6755$66fc32b05c2be8acc9f75eac3d87d3a88f513802
```

Is reversing this password encryption possible?

Comment: It's actually not encrypted.  It's hashed, making it theoretically impossible to reverse with absolute certainty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sha-1 is a one-way hash.  It cannot be reversed except for using a brute force attack which will take millions of years.

There are some online databases that let you reverse the hash of common words/conbinations of words.  However, django adds "salt" to the password before it computes the hash, so you cannot reverse django passwords.

That's why a hash is used.  Nobody can find out your password, not even sys admins :-)

Comment: A proof that p=np would mean that an algorithm exists

Comment: How does django decript it in order to user to get access to the admin panel?

Comment: It doesn't decrypt the original password. It encrypts your password attempt and compares it to the already encrypted passwd

Answer (score 19):

Yes, it's possible. All you need is a few million years, and a computer the size of our solar system.

Comment: Or a plasmobot... http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/08/090827073256.htm =)

Comment: @John you are too optimistic: you should first try strings from a dictionary (more likely, you should first "test", "password", "123"...). I bet the password would come out pretty soon in most cases.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's the point.

If your user forgot their password, you'll have to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Django is using **sha1** which is a one way hash for password hashing and **"salt"** the password before encrypting them. So it will take much longer time (maybe our lifetime) to decrypt them. The passwords are hashed so that no one will be able to decrypt it even if they have the hashed values.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti. I accept that. But the process will take much longer time. Thats why I used the word impossible. I'll correct it. Thanks for the advice.